# How do we map ACF File Field to WPForms File Upload field?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro, wpforms

I have an ACF(Advanced Custom Field) file field which required to be mapped with the front end WPForms File Upload field. When someone uploads a file via front-end WPForm form I need to see the file attachment in the WP Admin dashboard under ACF user meta as a file attachment.

I have created the file field in ACF.
WPForms have a File Upload field.

But in the WP admin, I cannot see the file attachment. WPForms entries are having attachments. How can I perform this?

Thanks.
Thusi

Answer (score 0):

When you download the spreadsheet you should be able to see the column for the attachment, if you don't, make sure to check the settings when creating the csv file.